# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, web-deployment, econnrefused

So I wanted to try making like a blog website with Node js and MongoDB. I’m a beginner with it so it’s kinda a mess, but everything worked fine locally (on localhost 3000). I found Railway as a free alternative to Heroku and tried to deploy my project there.

For some reason it failed to connect to the database, and [this](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#5uc1q6515dhys1rv0rp03) is what I got in the logs.

[Here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#t3x1fg82mie3ydhov6o59u) is a small piece of code from app.js

What could be the problem? I will share more code if it is needed.

Comment: Did you actually setup the heroku database in the Railway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem solved it its really simple
1.Start a mongodb service with railway you will have a new test database
2.Use the mongodb link provided with railway to connect to your new test database add this to your .env DB_URL it will now reflect your given mongodb link
3.commit the changes made to your .env DB_URL
4.Push the new changes to your github and it will now work